Karate Test: Call Navigate to Parent Folder
How do I navigate up a parent folder in Karate Testing? This seems to only add a .. to the file, and does not actually go up the folder tree.
* def result = karate.call('../karate/reusableFeatures/testData.feature', args)


Use the this: prefix to be very clear that it should be relative to "current feature file": https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#path-prefixes
But classpath: is also a good choice and recommended.
